# SQL Query Between Two Related Tables

Tags: sql

I am attempting to complete some tute work for new SQL course, and I am having trouble completing the following query.

> Provide a list of customers whose balance exceeds 5000 dollars

I have provided of copy of the ER diagram and schema below.

[ER Diagram & Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiS6G.png)

I just can not work my head around how to JOIN the two tables when they do not have a common ID.

Cheers!

Comment: you need to join 3 tables

Comment: You have the relation table `has`. That's where the "Common ID" (in other words "the relation between Customer and Account") is stored.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't explain my problem very well. I understand the 'has' table connects 'Customer' and 'Account', but I am struggling to work out how I connect the two in a SQL query to return the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join  across multiple tables in this situation.

For example

```
SELECT users.name FROM users
INNER JOIN has ON has.id = users.id
INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.accNumber = has.accNumber
WHERE accounts.balance > 5000
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for the help. It seems so simple now that it is written out!